# Defining the cover relation on the product of two lattices.

Tags: order-theory, lattice-orders

Suppose I have a lattice $\langle L, \preceq\rangle$. I know that the covering relation on the lattice is that $x\lessdot y$ if $x\prec y$ and there is no $z$ such that $x \prec z \prec y$.

Now suppose I define a new lattice as $L^{2}$, with vertices $(a\times b)$. The partial order relationship is $(a\times b)\preceq(a'\times b') \iff a\preceq a', b \preceq b'$, which is all well and good.

What I'm curious about is whether it is possible reconstruct the covering relation on $L^{2}$ from the covering relation on just $L$. Naively, I considered that, if $a\lessdot a', b\lessdot b'$, then $(a\times b)\lessdot (a'\times b')$, but working out some simple lattices by hand shows that this is not true.

Any help here would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: No, it's not like that. There was a question with a correct conjecture of what the covering relation should be, to which I answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3899046/303170). If you have further queries on this, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

How about $a \times b \lessdot a' \times b' \iff a \lessdot a' \ OR \ b \lessdot b'$ ?

If $a \times b \lessdot a' \times b'$ then

there is no $c$ such that $a \prec c \prec a'$. Hence  $a \lessdot a'$ .

or

there is no $d$ such that $b \prec d \prec b'$ . Hence  $b \lessdot b'$ .

Since if both holds for a $c,d$, we have $(a \times b) \prec (c\times d) \prec (a' \times b')$.